# Is it possible to use JsRender template in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsrender

i have develope angular.js application and i get the data through template. so i have using in jsRender as:

```
<script type="text/jsrender">
   <td>{{:StudentID}}</td>
```

but it is not working in angular js. but instead of using ng-template is working fine. my code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
<td>{{data.StudentID}}</td>
```

please advice is it possible to use jsRender template in angular js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you are using your JsRender template within your angular app. But if you are looking to have data-bound templates, with reactive dynamic updates to the UI when the data changes, then you probably need to choose either Angular (with Angular templates) or JsViews (with JsRender templates).

In fact JsViews is a layer on top of JsRender templates. A JsViews app is similar to an Angular app, with a similar set of features (observable data and dynamic data-bound templates) - but it uses JsRender templates. See 
[JsViews Quickstart](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsv-quickstart).